# How i can fetch the specific column from file and perform filter operation

Tags: filtering, export-to-csv

I need to read a 2 could from my csv file and im using below code to fetch the output data but the query is giving me blank output.

```
$b = Import-csv -path "C:\temp\provisioningresource.csv" | Select-Object "Global Id", "Profile Name"
$b
```

Also i have a column call "Profile name" which i need to filter with specific value from column and fetch only "Global Id" column to new file.
I have written below code which is working fine with small file but when i using my original file its generating blank file.

```
$ArrayList_2 = Import-CSV -path C:\temp\CKUNTMData.csv 

$ArrayList_2| ForEach-Object{

if($_."Profile Name" -like 'CKUNTM'){
    $_."Global Id".Substring(0,6)
}} | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\Output_2.csv
```

Please help me with fetch the Global id column by putting the filter condition on the Profile name column.

1. im not able to fetch the 2 columns data to a new file
2. With filter condition on the Profile name column grab global id column data to csv file.

I have tried below 2 script but its not working as expected.

1. Fetching column
   $b = Import-csv -path "C:\temp\provisioningresource.csv" | Select-Object "Global Id", "Profile Name"
   $b.count
   $b
2. filter
   $ArrayList_2 = Import-CSV -path C:\temp\CKUNTMData.csv

   $ArrayList_2| ForEach-Object{

   if($*."Profile Name" -like 'CKUNTM'){
   $*."Global Id".Substring(0,6)
   }} | Out-File -FilePath C:\temp\Output_2.csv